# should my raise statement be inside of the for loop

Tags: python, exception

I had a quick question regarding my code. Should this raise statement go outside or inside of the for loop? Would it get the error and raise it if it were outside?

```
try:
    for key, value in options:
        my_list.extend([key, value])
        raise ValueError
except ValueError as e:
    logger.debug('Too many options to unpaack: ', e)
```

Would my code be better like that or if the `raise ValueError` line didn't have the added indent and aligned with the beginning of the for loop?

Comment: That depends on what you want to achieve. The code you posted makes little sense to me in both variants :) when exactly do you raise the Exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no If Statement so , for your current code it always raise error in the first loop - for loop will run only once.
the raise error is unnecessary because when you wrap it with a try and expect if there is any ValueError it will catch it any way with the exception so you can just put it off

Comment: Thanks. I thought something was odd about that. Still getting used to trying to use raise statements when needed.

Comment: No problem  ;)  , I am glad that I helped to you